# How to set the ListObject in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just started combining json data with recyclerView. After checking ArrayList can completed save key and value

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

//set Attributes and storage List for json

    public String jsonData = "myurl";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

...

  private void loadingData() {//the method is called in onCreate

ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "update",
                "Loading Data", true);

//using Thread and Dialog while loading the data

        new Thread(() -> {

            try {

//use GetData(AsyncTask) & parse json
                String jsonOpendata = new GetData().execute(jsonData).get();

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonOpendata);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

//   Set key & value for Hashmap             
         
                  String Date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                    String[] dateFormat = Date.split("-");
                    switch (dateFormat[1]) {
                        case "1":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Jan.";
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Feb.";
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Mar.";
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Apr.";
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            dateFormat[1] = "May.";
                            break;
                        case "6":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Jun.";
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Jul.";
                            break;
                        case "8":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Aug.";
                            break;
                        case "9":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Sep.";
                            break;
                        case "10":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Oct.";
                            break;
                        case "11":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Nov.";
                            break;
                        case "12":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Dec.";
                            break;
                    }
                    String dateFormat = jsonObject.getString(String.valueOf(dateFormat)));

       HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("date", dateFormat);
                   ...

                    arrayList.add(hashMap);

                }
//loading completed Thread
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,4));
                    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
                    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                });
//catch....
```

And my recyclerView can read adapter and display the data successfully.
However, I found out the way more efficient and useful to save the data in arrayList is to put it into ListObject,so I've attempted it as follows

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {

//replacement

    public String jsonData = "myurl";

    **List<Book> bList = new ArrayList<>();**

...

  private void loadingData() {//the method is called in onCreate

//using Thread and Dialog while loading the data

//use GetData(AsyncTask) & parse json
              ...

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

//   Set key & value in Object
                    **Book book = new Book();**
                   String Date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                    String[] dateFormat = Date.split("-");
                    switch (dateFormat[1]) {
                        case "1":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Jan.";
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Feb.";
                            break;
                        case "3":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Mar.";
                            break;
                        case "4":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Apr.";
                            break;
                        case "5":
                            dateFormat[1] = "May.";
                            break;
                        case "6":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Jun.";
                            break;
                        case "7":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Jul.";
                            break;
                        case "8":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Aug.";
                            break;
                        case "9":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Sep.";
                            break;
                        case "10":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Oct.";
                            break;
                        case "11":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Nov.";
                            break;
                        case "12":
                            dateFormat[1] = "Dec.";
                            break;
                    }
                   **astro.setDate(jsonObject.getString(String.valueOf(dateFormat)));**
                   ...
                    **bList.add(book);**

                }
//loading completed Thread
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,4));
                    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
                    RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(**this,bList**);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                });
//catch....
```

Then add a Book class

```
public class Book {
    String date;

    public Book(String date) {
           this.date = date;
    }

    public Book() {
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date= date;
    }
```

And the errors occur said
*W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for [Ljava.lang.String;@1b3da99*
I will really appreciate if someone could give me any solution or direction to solve this problem

Comment: looks like there's no JSON payloads included as snippet code, you might wanna update it first, e.g: `{ "books": [ { "date": "1-12-2021", "title": "Book Wonderland!" } ] }`

Comment: @mochadwi I do have the json url data in json data attribute,but I replace it with myurl because of company confidential policy

Comment: `org.json.JSONException` possibly this is thrown because either the attributes is missing (no value), just for the e.g, expected: `{ "books": [] }, actual: {}

Comment: did you already place a breakpoint in `JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);` in case the exception thrown when trying to access the `JSONObject` by its index, that would be great, your current description seems still vagues to know which line throws the exception :pray:

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.The reason why the error tells
`W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for [Ljava.lang.String;@1b3da99`
is because that I shouldn't get jsonObject data and transfer the formation at the same time.

`book.setDate(jsonObject.getString(String.valueOf(dateFormat)));`

the key of value was named `'date'` in my json data.However, I thought it would be fine to run through the argument in `dateformat` and parse the value to string as an jsonObject value. jsonObject didn't have the key `'dateformat'` ,so there was no clue can find my value.The ide can only find automatic-generated id in dateformat and transfer it to String `@1b3da99` during the runtime.

the solution just seperate the procedure.
get the jsonObject in the main class

`book.setDate(jsonObject.getString("date"));`

`bList.add(book)`

and put the argument in the setDate.

`public void setDate(String date) {//dateFormat argument}`